# Datatype conversion using Python Marshmallow

Tags: python, python-3.x, marshmallow

I am trying to use Marshmallow schema to serialize the python object. Below is the schema I have defined for my data.

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields

class User:

    def __init__(self, name = None, age = None, is_active = None, details = None):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.is_active = is_active
        self.details = details

class UserSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.Str()
    age = fields.Int()
    is_active = fields.Bool()
    details = fields.Dict()
```

The input will be in dictionary format and all the values will be in string.

```
user_data = {"name":"xyz", "age":"20", "is_active": 'true',"details":"{'key1':'val1', 'key2':'val2'}"}
```

When I try to run the below snippet, values of **age** and **is_active** got converted into respective datatype but **details** remains unchanged.

```
user_schema = UserSchema()
user_dump_data = user_schema.dump(user_data)
print(user_dump_data)
```

Output:

```
{'name': 'xyz', 'is_active': True, 'details': "{'key1':'val1', 'key2':'val2'}", 'age': 20}
```

I need to serialize the input data into respective datatype I defined in my schema. Is there anything I am doing wrongly? Can anyone guide me how to acheive this using Marshmallow?

I am using

```
python 3.6
marshmallow 3.5.1
```

**Edit**

The above input data is fetched from HBase. By default HBase stores all its values as bytes and return as bytes. Below is the format I get from HBase

```
{b'name': b'xyz', b'age': b'20', b'is_active': b'true', b'details': b"{'key1':'val1', 'key2':'val2'}"}
```

Then I decode this dictionary and pass it to my UserSchema to serialize it to be used in web API.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing serializing (dumping) and deserializing (loading).

Dumping is going from object form to json-serializable basic python types (using `Schema.dump`) or json string (using `Schema.dumps`). Loading is the reverse operation.

Typically, your API loads (and validates) data from the outside world and dumps (without validation) your objects to the outside world.

If your input data is this data and you want to load it into objects, you need to use `load`, not `dump`.

```
user_data = {"name":"xyz", "age":"20", "is_active": 'true',"details":"{'key1':'val1', 'key2':'val2'}"}
user_loaded_data = user_schema.load(user_data)
user = User(**user_loaded_data)
```

Except if you do so, you'll be caught by another issue. `DictField` expects data as a `dict`, not a `str`. You need to enter

```
user_data = {"name":"xyz", "age":"20", "is_active": 'true',"details": {'key1':'val1', 'key2':'val2'}}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Yeah you are right I can use load, but I am trying to return the serialized data to a web application. I have edited the question

Comment: Use dump to dump an object with the schema to your API. To build the object with BD data, you may use schema.load, but typically, you'd use a Data Access Object or an ORM-like layer (like sql-alchemy).

Comment: If you go directly from DB to API, you don't need objects in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

As Jérôme mentioned you're confusing serializing(dumping) with deserializing(loading). As per your requirement, you should use `Schema.load` as suggested.

Since, all the input values are expected to be of string type. You can use, `pre_load` to register a method for pre-processing the data as follows:

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, pre_load

class UserSchema(Schema):
    name = fields.Str()
    age = fields.Int()
    is_active = fields.Bool()
    details = fields.Dict()

    @pre_load
    def pre_process_details(self, data, **kwarg):
        data['details'] = eval(data['details'])
        return data

user_data = {"name":"xyz", "age":"20", "is_active": 'true',"details":"{'key1':'val1', 'key2':'val2'}"}

user_schema = UserSchema()
user_loaded_data = user_schema.load(user_data)
print(user_loaded_data)
```

Here, `pre_process_details` will convert string type to dictionary for correct deserialization.

Comment: Using `eval` in an API is a red flag. Never eval outside world data. Using it on DB data might not be as dangerous, but it looks like a design issue.

Comment: @Jérôme Thanks for highlighting this & informing me about this red flag. My intent here was to inform about using `pre_load` if input is expected of type string. We can use other ways for converting string to dict, like `json.loads()` perhaps.